# Correctly use export = and export default in Typescript to create types for lighthouse

Tags: typescript, lighthouse

I'm trying to create a `.d.ts` for this lighthouse file and I strugle to understand how to deal with the default export

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/lighthouse-core/index.js#L28

```
module.exports = function(url, flags = {}, configJSON) {
  const startTime = Date.now();
  return Promise.resolve().then(_ => {
    // set logging preferences, assume quiet
    flags.logLevel = flags.logLevel || 'error';
    log.setLevel(flags.logLevel);

    // Use ConfigParser to generate a valid config file
    const config = new Config(configJSON, flags.configPath);

    const connection = new ChromeProtocol(flags.port, flags.hostname);

    // kick off a lighthouse run
    return Runner.run(connection, {url, flags, config})
      .then(lighthouseResults => {
        // Annotate with time to run lighthouse.
        const endTime = Date.now();
        lighthouseResults.timing = lighthouseResults.timing || {};
        lighthouseResults.timing.total = endTime - startTime;

        return lighthouseResults;
      });
  });
};

module.exports.getAuditList = Runner.getAuditList;
module.exports.traceCategories = require('./gather/driver').traceCategories;
module.exports.Audit = require('./audits/audit');
module.exports.Gatherer = require('./gather/gatherers/gatherer');
```

At this stage, I have a `lighthouse.d.ts` file in my project with:

```
declare module "lighthouse" {

  export interface flags {
    port: number;
    disableCpuThrottling: boolean;
    disableDeviceEmulation: boolean;
    disableNetworkThrottling: boolean;
  }

  export default function lighthouse(url: string, flags: flags, perfConfig: any): any
}
```

It seems to be typed properly. if I import using `import * as lighthouse from "lighthouse";`, I can do `lighthouse.default` and `lighthouse.flags` where I need.

But if I run my code, I get `TypeError: lighthouse.default is not a function`. Am I forced to use `export =`? If I don't have choice, how to use `export =` but export the function, the `flags` type, and `getAuditList`, `traceCategories`, `Audit`, `Gatherer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way that a commonjs module exports something as default ...

```
module.exports.default = ...;
```

... and there's no sign of it in the code sample. The module exports *just* one function and assign some properties to it. Try using this as a starting point for a .d.ts:

```
declare module "lighthouse" { // the module name must be in quotes

    const lighthouse: { // it must be a "const".

        //here starts the signature "(...): any " that describes the object as callable
        (url: string, 
         flags: { 
                     port?: number;                       // all of these flags keys must be "?"
                     disableCpuThrottling?: boolean;      // because the parameter initializer
                     disableDeviceEmulation?: boolean;    // is an empty {}
                     disableNetworkThrottling?: boolean;  //
         } = {}, 
         perfConfig: any): any; 


        //  and here are all the properties that the library has attached to the function.
        getAuditList: ...;    // 
        traceCategories: ...; //  give them the correct type for a better compiler support
        Audit: ...;           // 
        Gatherer: ...;        //
    }

    export = lighthouse; // <-finally
}
```

> And this is how it must be used in a .ts file

```
import * as lighthouse from "lighthouse";

lighthouse(...);                //<- invoke it directly
...lighthouse.traceCategories...; //<- get access to one of it's properties
```

Using *"export ="*  will not wrap the function inside an object so the transpiled .js file will be like:

```
var lighthouse = require("lighthouse");
lighthouse(...); // this is the desired result and not _whateverName.lighthouse(...);
```